# Simple on-demand function call tree in Python?

Tags: python, debugging, callstack

I'm working on a project with lots of calls to functions stored as `callable` instances and my only way to "debug" is writing on `stdout`. Also the project is massively nested and monolithic so to see what's going on by just adding `print`/`logging` statements leads to massive confusing output which - in the best case - just tells me where to place the next statement.

Since I can't easily change that situation I wonder if it's possible to get a readable call tree (with functions, files and arguments) from *one specific call* (rather than letting Python print all calls which results in millions of lines which don't tell me much).

Great would be something like:

```
with function_call_tracer():
    result = tree.handler_fn()(args)
```

producing something like

```
result = tree.handler_fn()(args=(1,2,3)) [<bound method foo.handler_fn of <Bar object at 0x7fe7748a9610>>]
> do_something(v=(1,2,3)) [<function do_something at 0x7fe778748a96>]
> > calc1(a=1)) [<calc1 do_something at 0x7fe577748a96>]
> > calc2(a=2)) [<calc2 do_something at 0x7fe756748a67>]
> > calc3(a=3)) [<calc3 do_something at 0x7dfe77435a78>]
> ...
> > ...
> > > ...
```

I know there is the `trace` module

```
import trace, sys
tracer = trace.Trace(trace=1, count=1)
tracer.runfunc(lambda: ruleset.valuespec().transform_value(param_copy)) \
    .results() \
    .write_results(show_missing=True, coverdir=".")
```

ant there are `pdb`, `sys.set_trace` and more - but I didn't figure out yet how to extract the information *what* function called *what* other function using *what* arguments in a way I can activate somewhere in the code and *deactivate* it afterwards.

Maybe I just use them not as intended - how would you get a call tree from a function call containing arguments?